# Quick Dialog like framework for Android?

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, gui-builder

I'm looking for something like Quick Dialog (http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog) which can be used to build and instantiate views for iOS  from a JSON file (or some representation). Is there any framework similar to that for Android which i can use to build my Android views from a JSON file or similar format ? Please let me know.

Quick Dialog JSON Builder: http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog/json-builder

Thank you.

Cheers,
Simith

Comment: If you're trying to get a quick answer from the user (yes/no, what's their name, etc), IMO, the built-in AlertDialog class is the way to go. For something that simple, it's going to be a lot more work to bring in a 3rd party library: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: Wesley, Thanks for your response, I'm not looking for a simple interface, i'm after a full fledged framework that can create views out of formats like json, xml etc. Quickdialog is a really cool one for iOS, was looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I just released an open-source library that offers this functionality on Android. It's called NexusDialog. Check it out here: https://github.com/dkharrat/NexusDialog

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks for the link. QuickDialog is really awesome for iOS, a similar offering for Android was lacking.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet seen a framework for android like QuickDialog, unfortunately.

The closest I've seen is MVVMCross, which builds on top of Mono For Android: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross.

Comment: Thanks for the link - we've got some experimental simple JSON-based UI building in Mvx now. We can build UIs from JSON like https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CustomerManagement/CustomerManagement%20-%20AutoViews/CustomerManagement.Droid/Assets/DefaultViews/DetailsCustomerViewModel/Dialog.json or we can build UIs across Touch and Droid from code like the AutoView methods in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CustomerManagement/CustomerManagement%20-%20AutoViews/CustomerManagement/ViewModels/DetailsCustomerViewModel.cs - WP7 currently under dev

Comment: Thanks Eduardo for the wonderful framework (QuickDialog) and the link you posted - i will check it out, Stuart i will check out what you have posted too, thanks.